# how to find the xor value of an array of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, xor

I want to find if frequency of all digits in a number is same. I used a digit array of size 10 (digit 0-9) and initialized it with the frequency of every digit.

```
eg: 221133
dig[] = {0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0};
and 
ans = dig[0];
for(a=1;a<10;a++)
{
    if(dig[a]!=0)
        ans = ans ^ dig[a];
}
```

How to find the xor value? 
it should return 0 meaning all non-zero elements are equal.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to XOR all non-zero values in an array. But why?

Comment: XOR equal to `0` will find if all the numbers occur an even number of times!

Comment: No - only the xor of *even counts* (2,4,6...) of identical values results in 0. If you want to know if they're all the same, find the first non-zero value and compare it against all the other non-zero values.

Comment: not too mention the false positives (e.g. 2 ^ 5 ^ 7 = 0)

Comment: ok. This is too useful. Thanks a ton. Was wondering how to deal with xor of odd count of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned int comments, XOR will not work for this; however, you can use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to solve this:

**Example**:

```
int [] dig = {0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0};

Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

for (int d : dig)
{
    if (d != 0)
        set.add(d);
}

// check for less than 2 since 1=only 1 val, and 0=no values other than 0
if (set.size() < 2)
    System.out.println("All values are the same");
else
    System.out.println("Not all values are the same");
```

Comment: @shylajhaa Why did you switch to the other answer that you needed to fix (i.e. not a complete solution)?

Answer (score 2):

If you "want to find if frequency of all digits in a number is same", then you should compare the elements, not XORing them...

```
public boolean isAllTheSame(int[] dig)
{
  int ans = dig[0];
  for ( int a = 1; a < 10; ++a )
  {
    if ( dig[a] != 0 )
    {
      if ( dig[a] != ans )
        return false;
      ans = dig[a];
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: this worked but with a small correction.  ans should be assigned the value of the first non-zero element in the array. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your first problem "check same frequency" :

```
int value = 2241133;
String[] digits = String.valueOf(value).split("");
boolean res = true;
int initFreq = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(digits), digits[0]);
for (String i : digits) {
    res = res && (Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(digits), i) == initFreq);
    if (!res) {
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(res);
```